# Cambiar masivamente de h2 a h3 en Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

tengo un sitio web en wordpress y quiero cambiar, de forma masiva, todos los h2 a h3 de mi página , se que es una petición extraña pero es un problema con un cliente, estoy usando el theme Composer, si alguien supiera como hacerlo me salvaría.

Comment: Wordpress guarda el contenido de los posts y páginas en la base de datos, puedes hacer una búsqueda allí para hacer el cambio en todos los posts y páginas de ese sitio. Estaríamos hablando de una consulta SQL que actúe sobre una tabla / columna específica. Si te interesa esa vía de solución puedo darte un ejemplo. Supongo que tienes acceso a la base de datos.

Comment: Una de las cosas buenas de Wordpress es que tienes plugins que te ayudan en casi cualquier cosa que te puedas imaginar. Yo elegiría la opción que te da @A.Cedano, así puedes realizar el update de una manera más controlada, pero existe un plugin que te hacer reemplazos en la DB de Wordpress. Antes de hacer cualquiera de los dos cosas te recomiendo tener a buen recaudo una copia de resguardo, por lo que pueda pasar. **https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/**

Comment: @PHPMyguel de acuerdo contigo en lo de hacer ante todo un backup de la base de datos. Pero evitaría recomendar plugin para resolver problemas puntuales. Es cierto que el uso de plugin facilita (a veces) las tareas. Pero tiene otros inconvenientes, como cargar el sitio, hacerlo inseguro (en el caso de plugin viejos que no se actualizan constantemente), impedirnos aprender cómo funciona realmente WP (esto es particularmente grave para alguien que maneja varios sitios como parece ser este caso), etc. Esta es una tarea básica para un admin que conviene aprender a resolver desde la base de datos.